# Cassandra duplicate tables for different partition keys?

Tags: cassandra

I have the following table, called inbox_items:

```
USE zwoop_chat
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inbox_items (
    postId text,
    userId text,
    partnerId text,
    fromUserId text,
    fromNickName text,
    fromAvatar text,
    toUserId text,
    toNickName text,
    toAvatar text,
    unread int static,
    lastMessage text,
    lastMessageDate timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((postId, userId), lastMessageDate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (lastMessageDate DESC);
```

The problem with this table is that I want to query it, both by postId and userId, as well as by userId only.

In other words, I have an inbox per post, but I have an inbox per user as well.

Afaik there is no good way to achieve this because:

1. The partition key(s) uniquely determine the node where the data is stored. I.e. all partition keys corresponding the where clause should be present.
2. Secondary index is no good fit for keys with high cardinality (in this case, postId has high cardinality)

The solution I currently see is to duplicate the table with different keys.
This feels like such an overkill though.

Is there a better solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming partitioning by userid alone would not generate partitions that are too large, you partition by userid, and have postid in the clustering key. You specified that you would query by :

> The problem with this table is that I want to query it, both by postId and userId, as well as by userId only.

So in this instance, you do not need postid within the partition key, but within the clustering key. The only issue is if you intend to query by postid alone as well - but that was not mentioned.

If the partition by userid will result in partitions that are too large, there is additional bucketing techniques available.

Comment: It's a straightforward solution I absolutely missed. Thank you. I'm not sure what order of magnitude 'too large' means in your definition. The number of records would correspond to all unique chat partners * posts over time. I.e. per post a user can have private conversations, and over time the number of posts will increase, hence the number of total records. You think this is manageable? As I understand initial db design is very important in Cassandra. (Edit: Are we speaking hundreds, thousands etc per partition? There won't be tens of thousands or millions)

Comment: It depends on the C* version but try avoid going over 100mb partitions and absolutely do not exceed 1Gb. Don't treat 100mb as a target, but a sensible maximum. It's not the row count per se (unless you get to cell count limits), its the size of the partition in total.

Comment: I would also add, if you time bound your queries, then you potentially could choose TWCS compaction strategy in addition, which helps matters, but while you have it in a clustering key, there was no mention of it within queries.

Comment: Time matters. I will have to calculate it, but intuitively I feel it will be enough. Given a few kB per record max, that's a lot of chat partners before reaching a single MB. Thanks.